# EC2 t2.micro instance becomes unresponsive to http queries

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, python

I am using ubuntu on EC2 instance. 
On top of that i am running a bottle framework. 
A python script is run in the background that serves for the http requests

Then i start running the script using "nohup sudo python abc.py &"
This serves the http post queries properly for a couple of hours. and i can see the incoming request in the logs at "/home/ubuntu/nohup.out"

After sometime i am unable to see the request logs in "/home/ubuntu/nohup.out" and the http request times out.

Trying it in postman gives the following error "could not get any response"

I want EC2 to process the request 24x7

Thank you for your time.
Regards.

Comment: What is the CPU steal and iowait percentages when this happens?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an EC2 problem, it sounds like a problem with your application. If you can log into your instance it's probably fine - if the EC2 instance becomes unresponsive to any request that would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Your EC2  micro instance is on cpu credits. The more you use, it will throttle you. So either httpd or some other application is using to much cpu. Wait for a while or restart apache to solve your problem.

Check your CPU and memory usage with top.